# Creating a predicate with variadic parameters

Tags: go

I am trying to create a function, takes in a predicate, and a list and calls the predicate on each item. I tried something like this

```
func hello(list []int, f func( int ) ) {
    for _, curr := range list {
        f(curr)
    }
}
```

The problem is, that my predicate may have other parameters that need to be passed in first, something like `func pred(a string, b string, curr int, c string)`. So now I cant just call hello without first creating a wrapper function which returns a function that only requires the int part (named curr). Is there a clean solution to this? I almost want to pass in a struct, where each key is a parameter name, and each value, the value to pass in as that parameter. But then I somehow need to leave the "int part" empty, and know to use it during the evalutation of `hello`. I'm not too familiar with interfaces, but maybe I can leverage them somehow? Not too sure what the best practices are for solving a problem of this type.

Comment: Can you give an example of a function where you might call this?  Where would the `a`, `b`, and `c` parameters come from?

Comment: I think "creating a wrapper function which returns a function that only requires the int part" is the right way to do it. Have you tried it? How was it not "clean"?

Comment: a,b,c would be known values at the time when I want to use the predicate

Comment: I tried it, and its fine, it just means I have to create a bunch of functions that are only called once, so it seems like a lot of overhead. I am mostly wondering if interfaces are a better way to go. Not too familiar with golang

Comment: if `a`, `b`, and `c` are known at the point you use the predicate, then you can still use a single-arg predicate: hello(list,func(curr int) { use a,b,c here })

Comment: What seems like a lot of overhead? Closures are used for “passing” data to function calls all the time, and are usually called once in that case.

Comment: "the best practices are for solving a problem of this type" Functions, function literals/closures. It really is that simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Function literals](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Function_literals) to solve this problem. The scenario in the question is an important use case for the feature:

```
hello([]int{1, 2, 3, 4}, func(cur int) { pred(a, b, cur, c) })
```

If `a`, `b` and `c` are in scope, there's no need for a function that returns a function as claimed in the question.

[See it in action on the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/nXh--GekEMM)